# Connecting new PostgreSQL 9.3 installation to a disconnected database

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I do not know what happened...I think lightening had something to do with it... In either case, a once happy and running PostgreSQL installation no longer exists on my windows 7 machine.  Not even the registery keys! So I reinstalled a new PostgreSQL 9.3 postmaster and system.

Is there any way of finding the old database with all my data and putting it back into the new installation? (If it helps any, the older installation was also version 9.3 and I am running on 64-bit windows 7 ultimate. The new installation is on drive C. The older one is on drive E. ).

Please Help Anybody  (all my data was in that database!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do no further harm

If this data is really important, before you do ANYTHING else, you should *disk image the computer*. Take a complete copy of the hard drive and put it somewhere safe. At the *very minimum*, take a complete copy of the entire old PostgreSQL install - the directory containing `bin`, `lib`, `data`, etc. If you put the `data` directory in a nonstandard location outside the PostgreSQL program dir you must copy that too.

You should always copy the current state of a damaged system before attempting *any* recovery. Failure to do so will make the problem worse. In this case, you certainly should not have installed the new copy of PostgreSQL without determining what'd happened and why - though I think you probably got away without doing any harm this time.

So. Done with the copy? No? Go do it, then come back.

### Got a datadir?

OK. So first you need to find out if you have an intact data directory and install location, and it's just the registry state etc that's gone. Go look in your install location in `E:`. Is there a `PostgreSQL\9.3\data` directory in there somewhere? Most likely there is. In that case, the simplest option will be to uninstall 9.3, then reinstall it with the same location as the old install. It won't overwrite the data directory that already exists (but you copied it anyway, right?) and everything should start up and "just work".

Failing that, you could instead stop the `postgresql` service via `services.msc`, rename the `data` directory in your empty new install in `c:` to `data.old`, copy the old `data` dir from `e:` to replace it, use the Security tab in Properties to set the security and ownership the same as the properties of `data.old`, and start the service back up in `services.msc`.

In either case, the new PostgreSQL binaries must be the same major (i.e. 9.3.x) and for the same architecture. You can't use a 32-bit PostgreSQL to read a 64-bit PostgreSQL's datadir or vice versa.

If it doesn't work as expected when you follow the above steps, look in the Windows Event Viewer for errors from the PostgreSQL service, and look in the PostgreSQL `data\pg_log` directory for PostgreSQL's own error logs.

### No datadir?

If you can't locate your data directory at all, you're in trouble. Search for a `PG_VERSION` file, or `postgresql.conf`, `pg_hba.conf` or `pg_control`. Those files usually exist inside the datadir (or the `global` subdir in the case of `pg_control`). If you can find them, you probably found the datadir, so see above.

### Still no datadir?

If you didn't find any sign of `PG_VERSION`, `pg_control`, etc, it's time to call a data forensics company to ask what it'll cost to try to recover from possible filesystem corruption or accidental deletion of a PostgreSQL database.

Expect to pay several hundred, minimum, more usually a couple of thousand.

### Cause

The symptoms you describe would fit with System Restore rolling the computer's state back to an earlier point in time after detecting registry hive corruption or some similar serious error that prevents the computer from starting up.

If that's the case, then you're probably OK, because it won't delete your existing files.

Unless you know that to be the case though, I'd treat the computer as very suspect. I'd do a S.M.A.R.T disk self-test, and I'd also do a filesystem check (properties tab on the hard drive letter(s)). I'd look at the Windows Event Viewer logs to see what errors were reported. If in doubt, I'd replace the system.

### Backups!

BTW, consider this a lesson in *backups* and why you should have them. On a different computer. Elsewhere.